# How do I call macros based on cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, type-mismatch

I'm brand new to vba, and I am struggling with trying to get a macro to start based on the value of a merged cell. Looking around online, I was able to get this far, but I keep getting error 13 type mismatch. Is there a way to compare a variant to a string or to set a cell to be something other than a variant by default? I've tried using CStr on Target.Value with no luck.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("B2:D2")
If Target.Value = "1756-L82E" Then
  Call p_1756
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A merged cell's value is in the top left cell - just use `Range("B2")`. This will fire though any time the selection changes, is that what you want? Or just when `B2` is selected?

Comment: I was wanting it to start only when the text was that specific value. It ended up working perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I keep getting error 13 type mismatch. Is there a way to compare a variant to a string [...]?

If the variant subtype can be coerced into a string, then you don't have anything to do, VBA will happily do the implicit type conversion and make you a string to compare against that string literal.

The problem is that `Variant` can be literally anything, and is *not* guaranteed to safely convert into a `String`. For example, a `Variant/Error` would result in exactly what you're experiencing - a type mismatch error.

> ```
> If Target.Value = "1756-L82E" Then
> ```

One solution could be to use the `Text` property instead of the `Value`. If the cell contains a `#REF!` error, then the text value will be "#REF!", and that happily compares to any other string literal.

Another solution could be to validate the `Variant` subtype, and making sure it's not `Error` - the `IsError` function does exactly that:

```
If IsError(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub

'here target.value is safe to compare
```

Now, there's another problem:

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
> Set Target = Range("B2:D2")
> ```

You're in a `SelectionChange` handler; the `Target` parameter is holding a reference to the cell that was selected - which is normally the single most important piece of information to have in that handler.

And the first thing you do, is overwrite it with a hard-coded, multiple-cells range: the variant subtype is `Variant()`, i.e. a 2D array of `Variant` values, each representing the value of an individual cell.

*That* is why you're getting a type mismatch: you're trying to get the `Value` of multiple cells at once, getting a `Variant()` back, and trying to compare that array to a string literal.

I suspect you're looking for something like this:

```
If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:D2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'Target is somewhere in B2:D2

If IsError(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub
'Target is holding a not-an-error value

If Target.Value = "1756-L82E" Then Call p_1756
```

Not sure though, it's hard to tell what you're actually trying to do. Note that the `Call` keyword is superfluous, but I'd recommend renaming the `p_1756` procedure to use a descriptive, meaningful name before removing the redundant `Call` keyword:

```
If Target.Value = "1756-L82E" Then CreateReportOrWhatever
```